# How to get data from dynamically created EditText views and insert it into an array?

Tags: android, loops, android-widget, android-arrayadapter

So basically what I need my program to do at this point is that when I click the submit button, I need to loop through each dynamic row of the ListView and grab the value in the EditText view and then insert that into an array which I will do further calculations after. Here is my code right now.

```
package com.hello_world;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.hello_world.ByteInputActivity.MyAdapter.ViewHolder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ByteInputActivity extends Activity {

private ListView myList;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private Integer resQuestions;
private Integer indexVal = 0;
private View caption;
ViewHolder holder;
ArrayList<Integer> intArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fieldlist);

    //Gets number of questions from MainActivity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        resQuestions = extras.getInt("index");
    }

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.FieldList);
    myList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_New);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount() ; i++) {
                View vListSortOrder;
                vListSortOrder = myList.getChildAt(i);     
                String temp = holder.caption.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("VALUES", "" +temp);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();

    public MyAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < resQuestions; i++) {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.caption = "Index " + i;
            listItem.indexText = "Index " + i;
            myItems.add(listItem);
            indexVal += 1;
        }       
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return myItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder.indexText = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.caption = (EditText) convertView .findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
        holder.caption.setText("");
        holder.caption.setId(position);

        holder.indexText.setText("Index " + position);
        holder.indexText.setId(position);

        //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
        holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    final int position = v.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                    myItems.set(position, Caption.getText().toString());                    
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

class ViewHolder {
    EditText caption;
    TextView indexText;
}

class ListItem {
    String caption;
    String indexText;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a code. Is it doing something wrong? And if not, what isn't it doing that you want? What have you tried to fix any of these issues?

Comment: The issue right now is that when I click the button it will only display the value from the last EditText view in my ListView. I need the loop to iterate through each row of the ListView and get the data specific from the EditText view in that row that the loop is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

Start with changing this:

```
public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();
```

into this:

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> myItems = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

then modify getView():

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder.indexText = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.caption = (EditText) convertView .findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
    holder.caption.setText(myItems.get(postition));

    holder.indexText.setText("Index " + position);

    //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                myItems.put(position, Caption.getText().toString());                    
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

and modify getItem(int position):

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return myItems.get(position);
}
```

for test parsing you can use something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount() ; i++) {
            String item = (Strng) myAdapter.getItem(position); 
                Log.e("VALUES", "" +item);
        }
    }
```

Didn't test the code yet, so let me know how it works, so I can correct it if need be.

Comment: Also, for setting mInflater you can use a shortcut: mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()); Better yet (I hope), pass the context to your constructor and use it from there.

Comment: Ok thanks so much, I actually just re-wrote my dynamic generating code to be more simplistic but this does work. This code was very sloppy.

Comment: OK! Just so you know, I think you shouldn't use views to store data - there should be some underlying data structure for that:) Life of a view can end unexpectedly:)

Comment: One more thing that, IMHO, you should not do is setting views ID like you did in getView - this is for identifying views in a layout, and getting them by findViewById.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am not sure how this works:

```
//we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                myItems.set(position, Caption.getText().toString());                    
            }
        }
    });
```

If you're trying to create an ArrayList of ListItem objects then you should be doing this:

```
//we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){

                //final int position = v.getId();
                //final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;

                ListItem litem = new ListItem();
                litem.caption = holder.caption.getText().toString();
                myItems.set(position, litem);                    
            }
        }
    });
```

Then from your submit button's OnClickListener you can do this:

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ViewHolder holder;

            for(int i = 0; i < myList.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) myList.getAdapter().getItem(i);

                String temp = holder.caption.getText().toString();

                Log.e("VALUES", "" + temp);
            }
        }
    });
```